# Can't add subview to UiButton

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I try to create a custom button with custom subview, but untortunately button appears without this custom subview.

```
public class ButtonWithSubview: UIButton {
    
    private var customView = UIView()
    
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.Player.roundedButtonBackground.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        prepareCustomView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func prepareCustomView() {
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(customView)
        self.addConstraints([
            customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            customView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            customView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

I create this button inside a cell of UICollectionView like this:

```
private func prepareCustomButton() {
    customButton = ButtonWithSubview(.custom)
    customButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play")?.resized(to: PlayerMetrics.playImageSize.value).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
    customButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 6, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    customButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    customButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(customButton)
    contentView.addConstraints([
        customButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        customButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
        customButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PlayerMetrics.largeButtonSize.value.width).withPriority(1000),
        customButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: PlayerMetrics.largeButtonSize.value.height).withPriority(1000)
    ])

}
```

I have no idea why  custom View is not visible and actual it is not visible also in Debug View Hierarchy mode. Do you maybe have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap constraints inside

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    // Here
 ])
```

Instead of `self.addConstraints([---])` and `contentView.addConstraints([---])`

Comment: why? i did it like this in whole application with hundreds of custom Views and everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, i can see that in other views, i activate constraints in layoutTrait(), thank you